# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling a Xib of a custom view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to make a custom view that can be used in the storyboard. Thing is it crashes when the view is instantiated. I don't understand the error or where I could pin point the the fault. Here are a couple images of my issues. [image]

[image]

If anybody could please help me. That would be much appreciated. If you need more details please tell me where to find the details that you need and I can fetch them for you.

Comment: The reason is clear: The outlet `view` is `nil`. Are you sure you want a subclass of UIView with an outlet of the same type?

Answer (score 1):

There's another great way to init custom view programmatically. You need to make the following:

**1. Write extension for your UIView class**

```
 extension UIView {
     class func initFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
     return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! T
     }
 }
```

**2. Create .swift and .xib files with the same name as your Class' name:**

[image]

**3. Inside your FMTextInputView.swift file you should init your nib:**

```
    private var param1: String!
    private var param2: String!

    //MARK: - init
    static func instantiate(param1: String, param2: String) -> FMTextInputView {
        let view: FMTextInputView = initFromNib()
        view.param1 = param1
        view.param2 = param2
        return view
    }
```

**4. Now you can use your custom view easily wherever you want:**

```
   let inputView = FMTextInputView.instantiate(param1: "Hello", param2: "world")
   self.view.addSubview(inputView)
```